# Why is scalar extension important?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, soft-question

What I want to know is maybe not as dumb as the bare question.

Suppose  B  is a commutative unital ring and  C  is a category of  B-modules.  Suppose that  f : A --> B  is a homomorphism, and  F  is a functor from  A-modules to  C  that is left-adjoint to scalar restriction on  C .  If the category  C  is suitably rich and  F  has good properties, can the situation serve as well as if  C  were all  B-modules and  F  were scalar extension with the same good properties?

Here is the specific example I am interested in.  Let  G  be a Gabriel filter on  A  and let  B  be the localization of  A  from  G .  (Actually, I am interested in the case of Nikolai Durov's generalized rings, but pretend I didn't say that.)  Then the localization-from-G  functor  F  on  A-modules has values in the category  C  of  B-modules  M  whose scalar restriction to  A  have the property:  For every member  J  of  G , the  A-morphism  M --> Hom(J,M)  is bijective.  The functor  F  is indeed left-adjoint on  C  to scalar restriction.  F  is always exact (maybe only left-exact, in the case of generalized rings).  The catch is that for  F  to coincide with scalar extension is one of several equivalent properties defining the "perfection" of the filter  G .  So the soft question for this case is:  Can, for some purposes, such a homomorphism serve as well as a flat extension?

Comment: I don't know about Gabriel filters, so I refer only to the second paragraph: For a homomorphism of (generalized) commutative rings $A \to B$ the scalar restriction functor $\mathrm{Mod}(B) \to \mathrm{Mod}(A)$ has always a left adjoint, namely the the scalar extension functor. Left adjoints are unique up to isomorphism, so your $F$ has to be scalar extension anyway. So I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Ah ok, you mean that $C$ is a full subcategory of $\mathrm{Mod}(B)$, not the whole category. Then it makes sense.